# Каким образом выводить блоки

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Делаю в админке создание блоков. Блок представляет из себя html содержимое. Каждому блоку присваиваю свое уникальное название, типа blockHead.

Вопрос: каким образом реализовать вывод этого блока при вставке чего-то типа:

```
{blockHead}
```

код страницы:

```
<?php
//подключение базы и прочих функций

  {blockHead}

?>
```

Название блоков хранятся в базе данных.

Каким образом реализовать подобное?

Comment: как минимум написать код замены этого шорт-кода на сформированный скриптом хтмл код.

Comment: Шаблонизатор используйте.

Comment: @Денис правильно ли я понял, что набор названий блоков присваивается вами изначально, а пользователь лишь использует их аки контейнеры для контента? Т.е блоки не генерируются, это просто набор?

Comment: @Visman может есть какие-то примеры? Что почитать ...

Comment: @KirillKorushkin да, все правильно

Comment: https://www.google.ru/search?q=php+%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B

Answer (score 2):

В вашем случае логичнее не использовать синтаксис шаблонизации а тупо подставлять блоки через условия. Судя по примеру в вопросе вы не юзаете `mvc` и логика у вас от представления не отделима. Тогда зачем изобретать велосипед =)

Например, собираете все пользовательские блоки запросом в массив, в котором ключ - это то самое название блока (оно же есть его позиция в шаблоне) а значение - сам код вставки:

```
Array [n](
    "blockHead" => Array(
        "enabled" => "1",
        "content" => "...content..."
    ),
    ...
    "blockFoot" =>  Array(
        "enabled" => "1",
        "content" => "...content..."
    )
)
```

Ну и дальше выводите их в своих местах:

```
<!--blockHead placing-->
    <?=($blocksArray['blockHead']['emabled']) ? $blockArray['blockHead']$ : '';?>
<!--/blockHead placing-->
```

З.Ы. Привитая мне бабушкой в детстве честность не позволяет назвать такую реализацию правильной (ибо много стандартов и махровых постулатов нарушается), но вполне обоснованным в рамках вопроса.